# Icon tooltip in HAML

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, haml

I am using this code for a tooltip on an icon in HAML.

```
%i.fa.fa-question-circle{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", "data-html"=>"true" ,:title => "REQUIRED DOCUMENTS"}
```

I want to change the style of default tooltip.
I tried this, but it's not working.

```
.tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #00acd6 !important;
   color: #fff;
}
```

And also the custom tooltip is not working.

Comment: If not a typo, `tooltip-inner` missed a dot, it should be `.tooltip-inner`

Comment: @eux, it's a typo. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: You could debug by browser inspect tool, to see which css rules block your custom style.

Comment: Yes, in my application.js, popper.min was defined after bootstrap, and I think that stopped Bootstrap to load run-time CSS on its default classes. I moved it above the require bootstrap and now it's working. But still, I had to apply the tooltip on an anchor tag as it's not getting applied on an icon tag.